# отображение кнопки после включения activity

Tags: android

Нужно включить отображение кнопки в моём коде.

id кнопки id="@+id/button1"

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    ImageView imageblackuot2;
    ImageButton button1;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageblackuot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackout_on2);
                /// отображение кнопки 
                /// button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); - не работает
            }
        }, 1100); 
}
```

activity_2.xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="267dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageblackuot"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blackout"
    android:onClick="sound_blackout"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:visibility="gone"
     />
```

Код ошибки:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ctos_exploit, PID: 30187
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.ctos_exploit.Activity2$10.run(Activity2.java:82)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8314)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30187 SIG: 9

Нужно всё делать только в этом коде

Comment: А в layout кнопка прописана?

Comment: Может `VISIBLE` вместо `INVISIBLE`

Comment: @Tamada, да прописана, добавил в шапке

Comment: @Nyuhnyash, да точно VISIBLE, но активити всё ещё вылетает

Comment: @En32, а приложите код ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: @Tamada, в том и дело, что компилирует нормально, но при работе вылетает

Comment: @En32 когда вылетает в дебаг режиме должны быть логи

Comment: @Nyuhnyash, добавил в шапку

Comment: Инициализируйте кнопку: `button1 = findviewbyid(R.id.button1)`, а потом можно вызывать setVisibility

Comment: Прежде чем использовать переменную `button1`, нужно присвоить ей значение. И чего вы добиваетесь не особо понятно. Зачем делать кнопку видимой на старте, если она по-умолчанию видимая? Просто уберите атрибут `android:visibility="gone"`.

Comment: @woesss, у меня идёт анимация, после чего кнопка должна становится видимой

Comment: @En32 но кнопку перед использованием setVisibility нужно инициализировать

Comment: @Tamada, спасибо помогли